# Sorting a dictionary of lists based on values of another dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary of lists of the form:

```
dict1 = { key1 : ['a', 'b'], key2: ['c', 'd'], key3: ['e']}
```

I have another dictionary which is of the form

```
dict2 = { a: 10, b: 11, c: 6, d: 15, e: 3}
```

I want to sort dict1 in reverse order based on values of dict 2, so the result would be something like:

```
sorted_dict = { key2:['d', 'c'], key1: ['b', 'a'], key3:['e']}
```

Edit: I need to preserve the order of keys. I could convert this as a tuple as well, which is perfectly acceptable.

Thank you!

Comment: a dictionary is not a sorted entity therefore even if you sort it it'll default back to the alphabetical sorting. If you're using a newer python version then there is no sorting.

Comment: @thethiny From my understanding, he is sorting the list rather than the dict keys.

Comment: @TYZ I thought so too but look at his "sorted_dict", he is sorting the keys of the dictionary.

Comment: @thethiny I didn't really find logic in the order of the keys in `sorted_dict` so I don't see that really matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort the dictionary values you can do:

```
sorted_dict = {
    key: sorted(value, key=lambda x: dict2.get(x, 0), reverse=True)
    for key, value in dict1.items()
}
```

Then to sort the dictionary(change the order of keys) you can do:

```
sorted_dict = dict(
    sorted(
        sorted_dict.items(),
        key=lambda x: sum(dict2.get(i, 0) for i in x[1]),
        reverse=True,
    )
)
```

---

A side note on the order of keys in [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

> Dictionaries preserve insertion order. Note that updating a key does
> not affect the order. Keys added after deletion are inserted at the
> end.
>
> Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion
> order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `key` argument in `sorted`:

```
sorted_dict = {}

for k in dict1:
    sorted_dict[k] = sorted(dict1[k], key=lambda v: dict2[v], reverse=True)
```

This gives:

```
{'key1': ['b', 'a'], 'key2': ['d', 'c'], 'key3': ['e']}
```

Comment: Don't you think you need to sort based on the total value of dict1 not just 1 value? `key=lambda x: sum([dict2[el] for el in dict1[x]])`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I added a minor edit that will preserve the order of keys. I want to sort the keys as well.

Comment: I didn't get the logic of sorting the keys, and I didn't get your previous comment of sort based on the total value. If you look at the sum of "a,b" and sum of "c,d" in `dict2`, they are the same (both 21).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sort a dictionary but you can sort a list. I suggest a similar approach to what I've done below that would sort the keys after mapping the values from dict2 then creates a new `unordered` dictionary from the sorted keys.

```
dict1 = { "key1" : ['a', 'b'], "key2": ['c', 'd'], "key3": ['e']}
dict2 = { "a": 10, "b": 11, "c": 6, "d": 15, "e": 3}
sorted_keys = sorted([key for key in dict1], key=lambda x: sum([dict2[el] for el in dict1[x]]), reverse=True)
sorted_dict = {k: dict1[k] for k in sorted_keys}
```

This produces

```
{'key1': ['b', 'a'], 'key2': ['d', 'c'], 'key3': ['e']}
```

sorted by the mapped value